# How to make jQuery function for not conflict

Tags: jquery

the problem is if i click radio button for tag id1 and then the both of query is runing the same, no error just double proces with 1 clicl for 2 query, so can i solve this ?

this my code in main.js

```
$('#tab_new_portofolio_pane').ready(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    var vals=$(this).val().split(",");
    var id=vals[0], portofolio=vals[1];
    $.ajax ({
      url : '../assets/php/admin_new_portofolio_setting.php',
      method : 'POST',
      data : {portofolio:portofolio,id:id},
      success:function(data){
          if (data === "showed") 
          {
            swal("Aktif !","");
          } else {
            swal("Tidak Aktif !","");
          }
      }
    })
 });
});
$('#tab_new_post_pane').ready(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    var vals=$(this).val().split(",");
    var id=vals[0], post=vals[1];
    $.ajax ({
      url : '../assets/php/admin_new_post_setting.php',
      method : 'POST',
      data : {post:post,id:id},
      success:function(data){
          if (data === "tampil") 
          {
            swal("Aktif !","");
          } else {
            swal("Tidak Aktif !","");
          }
      }
    })
 });
});
```

an this is my code for radio button

```
<div class="pull-right btn-group btn-group-toggle text-right data-click="view_new_quotes">
     <label class="btn btn-secondary p-1">
            <input type="radio" name="quotes" id="quotes" value="'.$a.',true"> Aktif
     </label>
     <label class="btn btn-danger p-1">
            <input type="radio" name="quotes" id="quotes" value="'.$a.',false"> Tidak
     </label>
```

Comment: Why do you have the same handler coded twice? Why not have it once within `$(function() { // here });` (or `$(document).ready(function() { // here });`)?

Comment: i use the php function with echo for my radio button for the (value='.$a.'), if i not use php function my radio button is not work